# How do I scrape just the first jpg image using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape just the first image url that contains a jpg. The code I currently have pulls all the jpg images when I just want the first one.

```
    images = soup.findAll('img', src=True)
    image_src = [x['src'] for x in images]
    image_src = [x for x in image_src if x.endswith('.jpg')]
    print('Number of Images: ', len(images))
    for image in image_src:
            print(image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add `break` after for loop instead, then it will break on the first iteration:

```
image = soup.findAll('img', src=True)
image_src = [x['src'] for x in images]
image_src = [x for x in image_src if x.endswith('.jpg')]
print('Number of Images: ', len(images))
for image in image_src:
  print(image)
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to scrape all the links to the images in the page, I used a wiki page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal').content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

for image_tag in image_tags:
    print(image_tag.get('src'))
```

First link is the first image in the page.
if you add a `break` at the end you will get the first image of the site.